# How to create Bar Charts dynamically in Primefaces 6.1?

Tags: java, jsf, charts, primefaces

I want to create multiple bar charts dynamically from java code using Primefaces 6.1,JSF 2.2, I have read and seen some previous examples in stack overflow , for example
[Primefaces 5.0 charts - how to create chart models and series dynamically entirely from database values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737416/primefaces-5-0-charts-how-to-create-chart-models-and-series-dynamically-entire) and [Dynamic generation of Bar Charts in Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999328/dynamic-generation-of-bar-charts-in-primefaces) 
 But didn't get any help. Below is xhtml and java code.

.xhtml code:

```
 <p:dataGrid value="#{newClass.xbarmod[0]}"  var="barmd">
 <p:chart  type="bar" model="#{barmd}" style="width: 450px; height: 450px"/> 
 </p:dataGrid>
```

java code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NewClass implements Serializable {
    private List xbarmod;
     public List<BarChartModel> ModelList() {
            xbarmod=new ArrayList();
        processModelList();
        return xbarmod;
    }
        public BarChartModel processModelList() {
            BarChartModel xtestmodel ;
            ChartSeries chartSer;
            for (int i = 0; i <1; i++) {
        xtestmodel = new BarChartModel();
        chartSer = new ChartSeries();
    for (int j=0;j<1;j++) {
                chartSer.set(0,10);
            }
            xtestmodel.addSeries(chartSer);
               xbarmod.add(xtestmodel);

            }
            for (Iterator it = xbarmod.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                BarChartModel b = (BarChartModel)it.next();
                xtestmodel = b;
                return xtestmodel;
            }
        return null;
    }
        public List getXbarmod() {return xbarmod;}
        public void setXbarmod(List xbarmod) {this.xbarmod = xbarmod;}
}
```

The above code is showing `No records` so it is cleared that i am doing some mistakes in java code or may be in .xhtml code, And also now there is no `<p:barChart>` tag available and there is no `ExtendedBarModel` class, so how to solve this problem now. Any suggestion/Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: 'Is not working' meaning it causes WW-III?

Comment: You are using this EL expression `model="#{barmd}"` but there is no `getBarmd()...` method anywhere in your java class.

Comment: @krokodilko `barmd` is a `var` of `p:dataGrid` , `xbarmod` is a List which contains barChartModel's and it has its getter and setter methods in java class.

Comment: With what? Your problem is unclear... You did not explain what it **is** doing, which parts ARE called etc... So I'm sorry, but I'm not trying to investigate since the link you refer to just works. Please clarify your problem

Comment: @Kukeltje I am trying to create bar charts dynamically in java code and then adding it to the list and then calling those multiple bar charts using p:dataGrid , but it seems i am doing some mistakes because it doesn't show me any Bar chart

Comment: I know what in general you are doing and if it does not show you any chart (a purely end-user observation). Then (like already stated in my previous comment)... What is it doing, what is called (is `#{newClass.xbarmod[0]}` empty?) what is in the 'page source'? Are there any error in a browser console... DEBUG... look at it from a developer perspective... investigate...

Comment: @Kukeltje there is no error in the browser console,

Comment: What about the all the other questions? We are not here to pull all sorts of info out of you. Some pro-active development skills are assumed...

Comment: @Kukeltje all the related code is above in the question and i have given information about the problem as much as i know it, what other type of information is required now?